# How to amplify ultra high-frequency signal

Tags: schematics, design, high-frequency

I have found some schematics to amplify ≈100 MHz signal, but can't find a schematic for 2.4 GHz and higher, up to 5+ GHz. The main problem I face is that I can't find a transistor fast and powerful enough for this.

Comment: At those frequencies, an integrated RF LNA is the preferred solution instead of discrete transistors. It really depends on the power output you need.

Comment: If the power level is part of the problem, then you should _edit your question_ to state it.  If you're well over the power level of available integrated solutions then you should consider other means.  Up to 1500W or so, there should be good information in the amateur radio literature on how to accomplish this.

Comment: For what purpose do you want this signal? What source and load impedance? Source power? Gain? Bandwidth? Linearity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an RF amplifier, the output and input need to be matched appropriately to the source and load. Matched transmission lines will need to be used for such small wavelengths.